# How to detect if the page is a Joomla article or category blog view

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to apply a class to a div according to a specific view of the page. If the page is a category blog view I want to add the class "blogview" else if the page is an article I want to apply the class "articleview". I would do this in the index.php file of my template. How could I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JRequest` is deprecated. Use `JFactory::getApplication()->input` instead. For example `JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('view')`

See: https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Answer (score 2):

You could handle this in a few ways but I've just created a $class variable and set it to the classes that you want based on the view / layout.

```
<?php
$joomlaApp = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$option = $joomlaApp->getCmd('option');
$view = $joomlaApp->getCmd('view');
$layout = $joomlaApp->getCmd('layout');
$class = '';

if ($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'article'){
    $class = 'articleview';
}elseif($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'category' && $layout == 'blog'){
    $class = 'blogview';
}
echo '<div class="'.$class.'">';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this way:

```
<?php
    if( JRequest::getVar( 'view' ) == 'article' )
    {
        $articleviewornot = "articleview";
    }
    if( JRequest::getVar( 'view' ) == 'category' )
    {
        $categoryviewornot = "categoryview";
    }
?>
```